# Kubuntu not bootable anymore

Tags: boot, kubuntu, services, gpt, mbr

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 and I getting stucked on a normal Boot operation with/after the `disk manager`

So I guess the problem is the `disk manager` or the service which should came next (would be nice to know the next service).

I am using a AMD CPU and GPU, everything was running fine untill an update. Since then I cleaned all not needed ppa (So steam, spotify and wineHQ) are still installed, but they should not interfere with the system. I compared all the packeges from a live system and install missing one and also reconfigure every packages `dpkg-reconfigure` without any change.

During the boot I do not see any failed services..

I would like to get it running again, without a clean reinstall.
Thank you for your time.

---

Edit

From an  old Boot.log it should stopp around here:

```
 Starting Snap Daemon...
 Starting Login Service...
 Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
 Starting Disk Manager...
 Starting LSB: This service…d stops the USB Arbitrator....
 Starting WPA supplicant...
 Starting Rotate log files...
 Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
```

Maybe the MBR/GPT sector of one drive is making trouble?

```
sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdc2 has 
                       1549178879 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 5844146175 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boot error was not done by the Harddrive and solved with the latest AMDGPU update(2020-12-17).
The Error with the sdc2 is that MBR do not allowed more than 2TB, so it has a dual MBR/GTP to solve this. I hope this will not case any problems.